# XmlSerializer deserialization UnknownAttribute event not firing for built-in types

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have an event handler for XmlSerializer's [`UnknownAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownattribute) event. This fires correctly if I have the following document:

```xml
<Document>
    <Test unknown="attribute">
        ...
    </Test>
</Document>
```

```cs
public class Test
{
    ...
}

public class Document
{
    public Test Test;
}
```

However, if instead there was an unknown attribute on one of the built in types, like string or list of strings, the event handler does not trigger:

```xml
<Document>
    <TestList unknown="attribute not triggered">
        ...
    </TestList>
    <StringField unknown="attribute not triggered">random</StringField>
</Document>
```

```cs
public class Document
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Test")]
    public List<string> TestList;
    public string StringField;
}
```

Any ideas for how to get this to fire the same UnknownAttribute event regardless of the element type it was placed on?

Example code to deserialize this is as follows:

```cs
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
serializer.UnknownAttribute += HandleUnknownAttribute

using (var reader = new FileStream("filename.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

...

public void HandleUnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e)
{
    // not triggered for TestList or StringField
}
```

Comment: Edited to include code to deserialize the example XML provided

Comment: I can confirm this, see the following demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GnCmVF.  Neither `UnknownAttribute` nor `UnknownNode` trigger for unknown attributes of list or string members.  This seems like a bug or limitation in `XmlSerializer`, you might want to report an issue to MSFT.  Are you interested in workarounds if they involve modifying your data model?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I can report this to MSFT and see if it's something they can take a look at. If there are any self-contained, simple workarounds that would solve this issue, that would be ideal - for example, I tried to see if there's a way to do a post-deserialize check, but that doesn't work because these attributes are dropped during deserialization (no way of seeing them in the resulting list or string objects). If not, it's not terribly urgent so I can probably just hold off on it for now